# Web automation using .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am a very newbie programmer. Does anyone of you know how to do Web automation with `C#`?
Basically, I just want auto implement some simple action on the web.
After I have opened up the web link, i just want to perform the actions below automatically.

1. Automatically Input some value and Click on "Run" button.
2. Check In the ComboBox and Click on "Download" button.

How can I do it with `C#`? My friend introduce me to use Powershell but I guess .Net do provide this kind of library too. Any suggestion or link for me to refer?

Comment: To check out and benchmark your program with standard tools you can try this automation library . pretty easy to use : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control ([MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). For testing, it allows your to do the things that could be done in a browser. It easily executes JavaScript without any additional effort. If something went wrong, you will be able to visually see the state that the site is in.

example:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.wikipedia.org/");            
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement search = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("searchInput");
    if(search != null)
    {
        search.SetAttribute("value", "Superman");
        foreach(HtmlElement ele in search.Parent.Children)
        {
            if (ele.TagName.ToLower() == "input" && ele.Name.ToLower() == "go")
            {
                ele.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

To answer your question: how to check a checkbox

for the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="testCheck"></input>
```

the code:

```
search = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("testCheck");
if (search != null)
    search.SetAttribute("checked", "true");
```

actually, the specific "how to" depends greatly on what is the actual HTML.

---

For handling your multi-threaded problem:

```
private delegate void StartTestHandler(string url);
private void StartTest(string url)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new StartTestHandler(StartTest), url);
    else
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }
}
```

`InvokeRequired`, checks whether the current thread is the UI thread (actually, the thread that the form was created in). If it is not, then it will try to run StartTest in the required thread.

Comment: what about check in a checkbox?

Comment: mun pieng, do u have any idea on it? It prompt out this error message --->  ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

Comment: @DEN, are you using multiple thread? or any background worker? When accessing the web browser it is important to make sure it runs in the UI thread. I will add an example of how this could be done in a while.

Comment: I'm trying it with the web form, asp.net visual studio 2008. Is that alright?

Comment: The name 'InvokeRequired' doesn't exist in the current content.

Comment: You are going to have problems using it on web form. InvokeRequired is a member of System.Windows.Forms.Control. Is your web form trying to open another page/website to get information (and this is hidden from the user)? Or are you trying to let the user see another page/website with some information already filled in?

Comment: i just want run it hidden from the user. so i should run it in windows form. I will have a try on that :)

Comment: mun pieng, how to get the URL on the next page after the "Superman" is inserted in the "searchInput" textbox and "Go" button in wikipedia is clicked with the code above?

Comment: `webBrowser1.Url.ToString()` returns you the raw string url. You could also check out `webBrowser1.Url` for other ways to get parts of the url.

Comment: what i get from that is http://www.wikipedia.org/ , which is the original one. I want to get the URL after the "Go" button has been clicked which is the next page. Any idea on that?

Comment: DocumentCompleted might be called a few times, depending on how many frames are in the site. I also corrected a bug where the "GO" button is not clicked. Please refer to edited answer.

Comment: mun pieng, how can i access the child window that pop up? is that possible to access it with WebBrowser??

Answer (score 5):

Check out SimpleBrowser, which is a fairly mature, lightweight browser automation library.

https://github.com/axefrog/SimpleBrowser

From the page:

> SimpleBrowser is a lightweight, yet
>   highly capable browser automation
>   engine designed for automation and
>   testing scenarios. It provides an
>   intuitive API that makes it simple to
>   quickly extract specific elements of a
>   page using a variety of matching
>   techniques, and then interact with
>   those elements with methods such as
>   Click(), SubmitForm() and many more.
>   SimpleBrowser does not support
>   JavaScript, but allows for manual
>   manipulation of the user agent,
>   referrer, request headers, form values
>   and other values before submission or
>   navigation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simulate a real browser then [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net) will be a good fit for you. (Selenium is another alternative, but I do not recommend it for you).

If you want to work on the HTTP level, then use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and related classes.

Comment: WatiN -> Dead link

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp).

A quick code sample below:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

// Requires reference to WebDriver.Support.dll
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

class GoogleSuggest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver.
        // Note that it is wrapped in a using clause so that the browser is closed 
        // and the webdriver is disposed (even in the face of exceptions).

        // Also note that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.

        // Further note that other drivers (InternetExplorerDriver,
        // ChromeDriver, etc.) will require further configuration 
        // before this example will work. See the wiki pages for the
        // individual drivers at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki
        // for further information.
        using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
        {
            //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
            //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

            // Find the text input element by its name
            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

            // Enter something to search for
            query.SendKeys("Cheese");

            // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
            query.Submit();

            // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
            // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(d => d.Title.StartsWith("cheese", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            // Should see: "Cheese - Google Search" (for an English locale)
            Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

The great thing (among others) about this approach is that you can easily switch the underlying browser implementations, just by specifying a different IWebDriver, like FirefoxDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, ChromeDriver, etc. This also means you can write 1 test and run it on multiple IWebDriver implementations, thus testing how the page works when viewed in Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc. People working in QA sector often use Selenium to write automated web page tests.

Comment: You would have to write a lot of code for even simple things in selenium , Use an abstraction like webbot on top of selenium that gives more features with short code :  https://github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot

Comment: I wouldn't quite agree with you. You do see that most of the code in the example is actually just comments. I don't see how webbot does it in a shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **ObjectForScripting** to automate WebBrowser, A Javascript callback to C# function and then function in c# extract data or automate many-thing.

I have clearly explained in the following link

[Web Automation using Web Browser and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/525426/Web-Automation)

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not have any built-in functionality for this. It does have the `WebClient` and `HttpRequest`/`HttpResponse` classes, but they are only building blocks.

Comment: John, so what should i do to implement the automation actions i mentioned above?

Comment: What do you mean, "open up the web link"?

Comment: sorry for my broken english. I mean, visit the web. For example, visit www.google.com and automatically input the search term and click on "Google Search" button

Comment: What kind of program will this be? If it's a GUI program, then you may want to use the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: actually there are a WEB, i want to input the search term, click on "Run" button and it will return a list of pdf file, and i would like to download it automatically. Just that simple.

Comment: @DEN: Do you mean it's an ASP.NET application?

Comment: not neccessary, it can be any other application as long as it is able to perform the actions that i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily automate client-side activity, like filling out forms or clicking on buttons from `C#`.  However, if you look into `JavaScript`, you may be able to better automate some of those things.  To really automate, you would need to reverse engineer the call made by clicking the button, and connect to the url directly, using the classes @John mentions.

Comment: seems hard for me. I will try to google out automation function for javascript

Comment: In javascript you have the same options like in C# so it's not easier there either.