# vb.net click a javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, forms

I have a vb.net Windows form.  In the form I am running a web browser control.  I am trying to click on a button using vb code.  I found this example of invoking a js function directly but I am not having any luck.  [How can I click a js button on VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656344/how-can-i-click-a-js-button-on-vb)

The html for the button is-

```
<input class="boldbutton" type="button" value="Verify"
   onclick="this.form.knob.value='ReqVerify';this.form.verify.value=1;this.form.submit()">
```

My vb code is-

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(
    "this.form.knob.value='ReqVerify';this.form.verify.value=1;this.form.submit()"
)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.  After the submit button is pressed there is a log that displays on the web page showing the activity.  I am not seeing any activity when running my script, only if I manually push the button from another browser (not the one in the windows form).

Comment: Why do you want to call web browser control from a *Windows Form* application? Both are different platforms.

Comment: My form performs a query on an access database.  It pulls results and stores them as a variable.  It uses the variable to open the correct web page.  Once the web page is opened it should click on the verify button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.  Here is my code

```
For Each el As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")
            If (el.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Verify")) Then
                el.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your vb.net's javascript call has no reference point for `this`. When you click the button in the web browser, `this` refers to the button.

When you call `WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript` `this` refers to something global, perhaps the window?

Either way, you can just invoke the button click. Do this by adding an id, for example `btnSubmit` to the button. Then do:

```
Dim search As HtmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnSubmit")     
If search IsNot Nothing Then        
      For Each ele as HtmlElement in search.Parent.Children
          If ele.TagName.ToLower() = "input" AndAlso ele.Id.ToLower() = "btnSubmit" Then                
              ele.InvokeMember("click")
              Exit For
          End If
      Next
  End If
```

Taken from (c#): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227644/1160796

**Another option** is to fix your javascript code. Do that by changing `this.form` to the form's id. Again, if there isn't an id then set one, ex `frmMain`. Then do:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("frmMain.knob.value='ReqVerify';frmMain.verify.value=1;frmMain.submit()")
```

**If you don't have the ability to change the website source** then use `document.forms`. Assuming it's the only form:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("document.forms(0).knob.value='ReqVerify';document.forms(0).verify.value=1;document.forms(0).submit()")
```

Comment: To get an element by id don't you need to see the id label?  I don't see that element listed on the page.  I see type="" and value="" but not id. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @JeremyTourville I was under the impression you created the website that you are interfacing with. My mistake.

Comment: @JeremyTourville There are 3 methods. Did you try the `document.forms(0)...` way?

Comment: I tried the document.forms(0) and frmMain method.  When I tried the get element by id method there was an error - "expression expected" on the line -If ele.TagName.ToLower() == "input" AndAlso ele.Id.ToLower() == "btnSubmit" Then  I did post my code as an answer above just so you could see it.  Everything works but the button click.

Comment: yea that was a typo from converting the c# to vb code. `==` isn't valid in vb.net. Needed to be `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VulnScanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=************")

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'opens connection to database
    con.Open()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://fs-enterprise.my.private.url/")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Logon").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub

Private Sub BtnQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnQuery.Click
    'open transaction object
    Dim trans As OleDb.OleDbTransaction
    trans = con.BeginTransaction
    'define the command which allows you to read, write or update the db
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    'define the query        
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Ticket ID] AS Ticket_ID FROM [Table_Main] WHERE ([Ticket Days OverDue] >= 1)"
    'assign the connection
    cmd.Connection = con
    'assign the transaction
    cmd.Transaction = trans
    'execte the command
    Dim myreader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While myreader.Read
        MsgBox(myreader.Item("Ticket_ID"))
        Dim result As String = myreader.Item("Ticket_ID")
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://fs-enterprise.my.private.url/remediation/ticket.exp?ticket=" & result)
        Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        '<input class="boldbutton" type="button" value="Verify" onclick="this.form.knob.value='ReqVerify';this.form.verify.value=1;this.form.submit()"></td>
        'WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("document.forms(0).knob.value='ReqVerify';document.forms(0).verify.value=1;document.forms(0).submit()")
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("this.form.knob.value='ReqVerify';this.form.verify.value=1;this.form.submit()")
        MessageBox.Show("Submitting Ticket")
    Loop
    myreader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class